# React native navigation v5 android back button handler

Tags: android, react-native, button, back, react-navigation-v5

I'm using react navigation v5 and I'm trying to make a default android back button handler inside routes.js. Using flux there was backAndroidHandler param which let you do this. My questios is there something i can use in navigation v5.

I know there is https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-android-back-button-handling/. But the problem is i don't want to go to every screen and set it.

Current solution is this:

```
  useEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      const onAndroidBack = () => {
      };

      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onAndroidBack);

      return () =>
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onAndroidBack);
    }, [])
  );
```

My question does navigation v5 have some kind of solution for this build in, like flux had?
Is there a better way to manage android back button?

Answer (score 1):

The solution the docs have in your link seem to be the best bet but I see one step missing.

You can make `ScreenWithCustomBackBehavior` return its children, making it a container instead of a component. Then wrapping this around each screen you need to customize does not seem to be overkill. And that solution is really if you need it to happen on focus. If you need a global android back button listener you can register it at the top level of your app.

Whatever the generally agreed upon solution will be, it will most likely either take the form of a container (like `ScreenWithCustomBackBehavior`) or registered listeners at the top level.